# Creating a AbstractModule to inject a dependency for a 3rd party library

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a 3rd party library that I am trying to inject the configuration into the constructor.
This is what I need to do:

```
class MyModule(configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
     bind(classOf[TwitterApi])
       .to(classOf[MyTwitterApi])
       .asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

The constructor of MyTwitterApi doesn't take a Play.api.Configuration but a typesafe.config.Config

```
class MyTwitterApi(config: Config) ...
```

So I need to do pass `configuration.underlying` to my constructor, how is this possible using DI in this AbstractModule?

**I need this instance to be a singleton also.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use provider to setup your module with eagerSingleton

```scala
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provider}

class MyModule(configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
     val twitterApiProvider: Provider[TwitterApi] = 
       () => new MyTwitterApi(configuration.underlying)
     bind(classOf[TwitterApi])
       .toProvider(twitterApiProvider)
       .asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

You can find a working example with sample classes at - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sarveshseri/ujwvJJNnTpiWDqdkBJQoFw/2

Comment: I'm not sure what a provider is, in my other classes that will take the TwitterApi in their constructors, do I use ```TwitterApi``` or ?

Comment: A `Provider` is something that provides an instance for a type. Also called a factory. You can inject `TwitterApi` in your other classes.

Comment: I think this is strictly the same as what I suggested although I admit it's more clearly set as a singleton.

Comment: @Blankman Provider is `com.google.inject.Provider`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```scala
class MyModule(configuration: Configuration) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
     val myTwitterApiInstance = new MyTwitterApi(configuration.underlying)
     bind(classOf[TwitterApi])
       .toInstance(myTwitterApiInstance)
  }
}
```

---

Or another approach would be to provide a binding for `Config` but if your `MyTwitterApi` doesn't have `@Inject` annotation this won't help.

Comment: I need this to be a singleton, will this be one?

Comment: I think so as it will always provide the same instance created in the `configure` method.